# What happens when I publish an MVC3 based web solution with multiple startup projects?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-web-developer-2010

My solution has multiple start-up projects in it. When publishing to production, the projects start up, but then begin to act in unexpected ways. I'm guessing I don't understand the system well enough yet.

What happens to a web solution with multiple start-up projects when it is published to the web-server?

Comment: What are your other startup projects? Do they also run on IIS? Or are they console apps, scheduled tasks, etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Startup project" simply means which projects start when you press F5 in the Visual Studio IDE.

They have no impact on the deployed web application.

---

In the spirit of the holidays, I decided to ask myself if there was any way you could be correct in any degree other than zero. I found a "5%" possibility:

Are these other projects necessary for the correct behavior of your web application? You mentioned that they are "Console apps/scheduled tasks". Does your application require that these console apps or scheduled tasks are running on the web server before your web application will function?

If that's the case, then you should be informed that startup projects "have no impact on the deployed web application". The fact that you have this code listed as startup projects will not cause the console apps or scheduled tasks to run on, or even to be deployed to, the web server. You will have to deploy these .exe files to the server and you will have to start them yourself. "Startup projects" won't do this for you.

---

If that's not it, then I think this question should be closed as "not a real question" until you narrow down what your problem is. My answer has told you what startup projects do not do, but in order to solve your problem, you'll need to figure out what the actual problem is.

Comment: Does that mean that the deployed web application will behave differently? If there are multiple projects marked as "startup projects", that information will be ignored? Which project will "run" then?

Comment: This answer appears to be incorrect. See here: "You can select which project or projects within a solution will be the first built, debugged, and deployed Visual Studio, and be run first when a solution is deployed." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1awth7y(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: First of all, note that your link is from Visual Studio 2005. If that's not the version you're using, then you should look at the documentation for the correct version. Secondly, no, startup projects have nothing at all to do with how the site behaves once it is deployed. Similarly, the "startup page" is not necessarily the first page a user sees when he browses to your site.

Comment: Note especially that the "startup project" concept is not specific to web applications. It means which of all the projects, of all kinds, that are part of your solution, will be "started" when the solution is debugged or started. Your solution is not deployed to the web server - projects within your solution may be deployed. Therefore, the idea of startup projects makes no sense in the context of the web server. It doesn't even know that the web site came from a project in a solution.

Comment: That looks like the correct source of documentation - if it's not correct, can you please point me to the right one?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1awth7y.aspx. In general, you don't want to use the MSDN URL that has a version number in parentheses, unless you are deliberately linking to a specific version.

Comment: But more importantly, you are misunderstanding what a startup project is. It is purely a feature of Visual Studio, and not a feature of any code you develop _using_ Visual Studio. Remember that you could use **Notepad** to develop your site, and get all the features of ASP.NET. Notepad doesn't have a concept of startup project.

Comment: What you're telling me doesn't match what I am experiencing, and is contradicting the documentation you linked to (unless I'm reading it wrong?). As far as I can tell, yes, the concept of different startup projects is relevant to ASP.NET (load order is the first obvious feature that is affected, as well as decisions around which configuration files are used, where resources are located). Back to my original question - is there a good solid discussion somewhere of all of the effects, and how they interact with each other?

Comment: Sorry, I can't help your misunderstanding. Try to take it from someone who has developed ASP.NET applications since .NET 1.0 that startup projects have nothing to do with anything except Visual Studio.

Comment: What do you think "startup" even means in the context of a web application? Web applications don't "start up". What do you think it means in the context of console or desktop applications? They don't "start up" until a user starts them.

Comment: I imagine that when web applications "start up" initial application state is loaded and configured in memory, appropriate resources are set up to receive and transform data, processes/threads are fired of to listen to correct ports, with the correct routing and other rules in place, etc... It would be very disconcerting to the end user, I imagine, to have to wait a few extra seconds (if they happen to be the first user to hit a web site) before all of the server side state is set up properly.

Comment: Sorry, you totally don't understand ASP.NET. Web applications have no concept of starting in the sense of "startup project". They are "started" upon the first access. Starting doesn't do anything except handle the `Application_Start` event in the Global.asax (if any), and then executing the request. Nothing else that you mention even exists in ASP.NET, in general (though I suppose you could do something like that in a specific application). You should talk to a more experienced developer whose word you trust if you refuse to trust mine.

Comment: I think that's the point - I don't understand it, and I'm looking for a good reference to learn more. The reference provided in your link seems to contradict what you're saying, so I'm not sure if that makes it good, or bad?

Comment: Just stop! You can't learn this stuff a little here and a little there. You've managed to totally confuse yourself, and you refuse to listen. The idea that "startup project" means something outside of the IDE is patently absurd, and I've pointed that out to you, and you _still don't get it_. Just stop, and proceed on the assumption that your problem has **nothing to do with startup projects**. That's the only way you'll find the solution to your problem. If you find yourself thinking about startup projects again, then just **STOP**!

Comment: Removed my request for documentation into a separate question